# adding data in gridview (web application) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview in my web application

this grid view is supposed to show 3 columns (tables, columns, new_columns)

[image]

I want to show grid view in click event in which I want to bind all tables in first Field(tables) and bind all respective columns of each table in dropdown list inside the gridview and also bind all new columns in second drop down list

here is the code

```
        DataTable test = new DataTable();
        DataTable _dbtest = new DataTable();
        list_of_table_of_old_database = db.Select("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + old_database.Text.Trim() + "' ", "");
        list_of_table_of_current_database = db.Select("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + new_database.Text.Trim() + "' ", "");

        DataView view = new DataView(list_of_table_of_old_database);


        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();


        test = db.Select("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "select  distinct k.table1 from (SELECT TABLE_NAME as table1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + old_database.Text.Trim() + "') as k INNER JOIN (SELECT TABLE_NAME as table2 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + new_database.Text.Trim() + "')as a;", "");




        DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
        DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, "--select--");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                _dbtest = db.Select("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "select a.fieldname from (SELECT COLUMN_NAME as fieldname FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + old_database.Text.Trim() + "' and TABLE_NAME =  '" + test.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "') as A LEFT JOIN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME as fieldname FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + new_database.Text.Trim() + "' and TABLE_NAME =  '" + test.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "') B on (A.fieldname = B.fieldname) where B.fieldname is null ", "");

                if (_dbtest.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    //here i want to display all tables in the gridview row by row (test.Rows[i][0].ToString())


                } 

                  // and i want to bind all columns (_dbtest) of each tables inside the loop in first dropdownlist in gridview 

                 // and same  columns (_dbtest) of each tables inside the loop in second dropdownlist in gridview
            }
```

I want to find some ways to bind data in gridview while I am running the loop, so I can give each field the right data

and this is the HTML code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Height="237px" Width="632px" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField FooterText="tables" HeaderText="tables">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField FooterText="columns" HeaderText="columns">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcolumns" runat="server" 
                         Height="16px" Width="181px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField FooterText="vms-columns" HeaderText="vms-columns">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_vms_columns" runat="server" 
                         Height="20px" Width="153px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

so at the end, this grid view will show all tables in grid view and each column of that table

Answer (score 0):

First step is load all tables and binding it to your gridView. You won`t use the event **GridView1_RowDataBound** to do that.

After you have load your tables you can use the event **GridView1_RowDataBound** to populate the DropDownLists. You can find a few examples explaining how to do that:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-populate-DropDownList-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

https://codepedia.info/bind-dropdownlist-inside-gridview-edit-template/